# Dynamic If else statement, value for condition is from database

Tags: if-statement, laravel-5, dynamic

is there a way to make this if else condition:

```
$searchUserTypeName = UserType::findOrFail(1);
success = true;
$message = '';
$user = new User();

if ($searchUserTypeName->name == "Captain" || $searchUserTypeName->name == "Member") {
  $fields = [
    'teacher_id' => 'Teacher Id',
    'team_id' => 'Team',
    'mobile' => 'Mobile',
    'launched_date' => 'Launched Date',
    'endorsed_date' => 'Endorsed Date'
  ];
} else if ($searchUserTypeName->name == "Mentor" || $searchUserTypeName->name == "Mentee") {
  $fields = [
   'teacher_id' => 'Teacher Id',
   'team_id' => 'Team',
   'skype_id' => 'Skype Id',
   'google_hangouts' => 'Google Hangouts',
   'graduation_date' => 'Graduation Date',
   'launched_date' => 'Launched Date',
   'endorsed_date' => 'Endorsed Date'
  ];
}
foreach ($fields as $key => $field) {
  if (!$request->has($key) || $request->{$key} == '') {
       $success = false;
       $message .= $field . ' is required.<br>';
     } else {
       $user->{$key} = $request->{$key};
     }
  }

  if (!$success) {
      $this->setStatus(400);
      $this->setSuccess(false);
      $this->setMessage($message);
      return $this->sendResponse($fields);
  }
$user->save();
```

to dynamic?

The value Captain, Member, Mentor and Mentee is from a mysql table
if Captain or Member
there is a specific field select that will save on the use tabel
same as for Mentor and Mentee

hope you can help

thanks

Comment: What exactly you want to do with this ?
Like what kind of algo you want with the conditions?

Comment: @AkhzarJaved I want to create a dyamic if else were if i input captain or member there is a specific fields will save to the database else if mentor or mentee same function but different fields. will update my code..

Answer (score 0):

You can set method in your related model

```php
User extends Model {

    public function isName(...$names)
    {
        return in_array($this->name, $names);
    }
}
```

```php
if ($user->isName('Captain', 'Member')) {
  //
}
```